How can I see the size of an archive on archive.org?
E.g., https://archive.org/details/stack-exchange-images. How can I see the size of that archive, without having to download all the files or manually do the sum of the all file sizes?

Many archives on archive.org have a torrent file automatically generated by archive.org. Loading the torrent will show the total size of the archive without having to download the files, e.g.:

